# nmp install on bundled meteor app failing

Tags: meteor, npm

I'm trying to re-deploy a meteor app that I've bundled and deployed on numerous occasions on the same machine but am currently not able to update or install any npm packages for some reason.

If I change to the programs/server directory and run sudo npm install I get

```
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-1.0.5.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-support/-/source-map-support-0.2.8.tgz
```

I've tried both the http and https registry prefixes and have discovered that I can download the fibers .tgz package on my mac fine, I can curl http://registry.npmjs.org from the host fine, but I can't curl or wget the package from registry.npmjs.org because I get "connection reset" errors (which I assume is why install is failing).

```
wget http://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/~/fibers-1.0.5.tgz
--2018-06-01 08:52:56--  http://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/~/fibers-1.0.5.tgz
Resolving registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)... 104.18.98.96, 104.18.94.96, 104.18.95.96, ...
Connecting to registry.npmjs.org (registry.npmjs.org)|104.18.98.96|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this, I'm at a bit of a loss. There have been no network changes at my end that would be causing this, and it all worked a few weeks ago quite happily.

Comment: sounds a like a network/firewall issue on your side, not related to npm (or meteor).

Answer (score 0):

Something very odd is going on with the networking to registry.npmjs.org as pointed out by Christian.

I did eventually manage to get the wget to run on this machine after trace routing to the end point first. Still not 100% reliable, but I got the deployment done.

Not really sure what's going on, but was networking for sure.